# Проблема с форматированием в My Complier Online IDE

Tags: mysql

Создаю таблицы через Create Table, далее делаю в них Insert и все форматирование слетает.

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    product_id INT Primary Key auto_increment,
    product_name Text not null 
);
INSERT INTO products (product_name) VALUES 
('Щетка'),
('Паста'),
('Вода'),
('Телефон'),
('Сухарики'),
('Колбаса'),
('Хлеб'),
('Носки'),
('Макароны'),
('Гречка');
```

Диалект MySQL
В результате получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы про что контент столбика вам выводит не под заголовком что ли?

Comment: MySQL отдаёт результат. А форматирует его используемый клиент. Вот ему и предъявляйте претензии. А лучше не предъявляйте. Ибо данные он отобразил правильно, а об их внешнем виде он заботиться не обязан. А не нравится - настройте его соотв. образом. Например. увеличьте дефолтный отступ табуляций.